# how to save an image after being cropped?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am doing a app that calls the camera of the phone then it will automatically crop, I wanted it to save the cropped image but it can't save any of it. Only the original captured image. but there are no errors in the code. The images will be use to be avatars in a two player game. Any ideas?

Comment: Also handy to post the code, where you try to crop and save the image. That way we can also see where it possible goes wrong.

Comment: here is the code to my app, i have posted before a question and rose another issue. thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824154/failure-delivering-resultinfo-on-cameraapplication

Comment: I looked at your code, but isn't it easier to just take the original bitmap and crop/scale that, something like: `cropped_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, destinationWidth, destinationHeight, filter);`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
       cropped_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You also have to add this permission in the manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```